# Excel Referencing cell entries for use in formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure exactly what to call what I'm trying to do, so searching it has been tough.  Basically I have a table of equations, each row has a different equations/references a different column, but all of them reference the same range of rows. i.e.  Eq. A = average(A200:A400), Eq. B = sum(C200:C400), etc...

From file to file the range of rows changes, so what I want to do is be able to do is enter the start and end rows into cells and have them auto populate the equations.  If anyone could tell me how to do it just for one cell and not an entire table, I could figure it out from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `INDIRECT` function would accomplish this. It allows you to enter in text to be interpreted as a cell reference.

For instance, lets say you wanted the range to cover `A200:A400` for a given sheet, and you wanted that desginated in cell `A1` of that sheet. In cell `A1` you would just type in "A200:A400" then, in the actual equations, you would have:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(A1))
```

You can obviously split this further down, but thats the concept of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form with a few text boxes. Enter the start and end row. Then your code could go through and enter the formula.

Something like this.

```
Dim lRow as long
Dim lEnd as long

lRow = val(txtBoxStartRow.text)
lEnd = val(txtBoxEndRow.text)

ws.Range("A" & lEnd + 1).Formula = "=average(A" & lRow & ":A" & lEnd & ")"
ws.Range("C" & lEnd + 1).Formula = "=average(C" & lRow & ":C" & lEnd & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS($B$1;ROW())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS($B$2;ROW())))
```

In that code I'm assuming cells B1 and B2 contain the limits (you can replace these references with hard number), to use your example: B1 = 200 and B2 = 400.

If you then place this code in any row, you'd get average("rowNumber"200:"rowNumber"400).

Address() gives you the right range reference
Indirect() makes a range out of it
Then you can wrap it in whatever function you like.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to try this. I'm working on it now, but how do I specify column?  Does it work on whatever column the formula was entered?

Comment: it uses the row on which the formula is entered (=row()) as definition for column which is to be processed in the formula. So if you enter this formula on 3rd row, the processed will be the 3rd column, and so on.
It doesn't matter which column the formula is entered on.
Be careful though about not having the formula in the same row as column, that would cause circular reference.